# How to rewrite the field of a view with Twig

Tags: views, 8, theming

I created a view with the machine name `cgv_product`.

This view contains the fields "Product Name" and "Custom Text".

In the "Custom Text" field, the `{{ name }}` Twig code is available to display the product number.

I created a template with the name `views-view-fields--cgv_produit.html.twig` it works but if I put the Twig code `{{ name }}` in it it's not rendered.

How to display the product name in my template via Twig?

```
views-view-fields--cgv_product.html.twig
```

I tested the following codes in Twig and it does not work :

```
    <div class="flex-grow-1 bd-highlight"><i class="fas fa-signature fa-lg"></i>
      {{ fields.name.content }}
      {{ fields.field_name.content }}
      {{ row.content.name }}
      {{ name }}
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

In the "Custom Text" field, `{{ name }}` is only available to render the "Product Name" field inside the "Custom Text" field (in the view UI), not in a twig template.

You should try to access your fields in the twig template like this `{{ row.content.name }}` (check the available fields using devel/kint).

Comment: I updated the question. I do not know how to use devel/kint

Comment: @marsouin – Download Devel, enabel Devel's sub-module Kint and then `{{ kint() }}`.